# WebAssemblyHostBuilder does not contain a definition for Host and no accessible extension method Host accepting a first argument of type

Tags: asp.net, correlation, serilog, host

I have an ASP dotnet core project running with blazoradmin, and i am trying to setup serlilog to enable log correlation, but while setting up correlation configuration i am getting below error

Error:

> WebAssemblyHostBuilder does not contain a definition for Host and no accessible extension method Host accepting a first argument of type WebassemblyHostBuilder could not be found

[image]

[image]

Program.cs Configuration

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BlazorAdmin;
using BlazorAdmin.Services;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using BlazorShared;
using BlazorShared.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Formatting.Json;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Logging.AddConsole();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("externalapi-client", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");
});

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, lc) => lc
    .Enrich.WithCorrelationIdHeader("TRACE.ID")
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo()
    .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), "D:\\log\\web1.log.txt"));
```

To resolve the issue i have installed the recommended packages but I am still encountering the same issue

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` and `Serilog.Sinks.BrowserConsole` and try using the following setup:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Warning()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"))
    .WriteTo.BrowserConsole()
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
    .ClearProviders()
    .AddSerilog(dispose: true));
```

After that injecting `ILogger` should work.

Comment: Hello Thank you sharing the responce but i am still facing the same issue as Host not resolving yet

Comment: Hi Guru Stron,

Thank you for sharing the responce as per the it will be enabling the ILogger and Configuration but my issue is with serilog correlation method. where i want to capture the correlation id & write to file 

However i have tried following the responce but still Hoste error remain the same

Comment: @pratikshatiwari use my answer, there is no `Host` property on `WebAssemblyHostBuilder`.

Comment: Hi Guru, 

Does it means i need to replace my below configuration with the one you shared? but main motive is to get the correlation id in each request log and save it in log file.


builder.Logging.AddConsole();
......
.....
    .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(), "D:\\log\\web1.log.txt"));

Comment: @pratikshatiwari yes

Comment: Hello I tried it and it is logging the correlation id only if i restart the asp dotnet service but when i am working on application from web it is not logging anything. main goal was to get the correlation id to each request we hit from web it should get logged. we have microservice based ecommerce web application running on asp dotnet.  e.g. log each request hit on https://localhost